# How to fix Path Manipulation error in java which is raised in Fortify

Tags: java

How to fix Path Manipulation error in java which is raised in Fortify ? Please provide any inputs?

I am getting the Path manipulation error in below line of my java file.

> > > > > new File(args[0])

Comment: Welcome to security.SE. You should add some more information to your question, as it is currently unclear. What do you mean by "path manipulation"? Directory traversal? Is this from a fortify web scan, or from a static code analysis? Ie, do you want to know how to fix a vulnerability (this is well-covered, and you should do some research before asking a more concrete question), or do you want to know how to suppress a false-positive (this would likely be off-topic, you should just ask the vendor)? I'm voting to close for now as unclear.